# AngularJS - Have $StateProvider query for dynamic data in app.config

Tags: angularjs, breeze

**This works, but Json is not how I want to retrieve the data:**

```
var states = [
{ name: 'main', url: '/', templateUrl: '/views/main.html', controller: 'MainCtrl' },
{ name: 'login', url: '', templateUrl: '/views/login-form.html', controller: 'LoginCtrl' },
{ name: 'logout', url: '', templateUrl: '', controller: 'LogoutCtrl' },
    {
        name: 'sales',
        url: '',
        templateUrl: '/views/sales-data.html',
        controller: 'SalesDataCtrl',
        resolve: {
            user: 'User',
            authenticationRequired:
            ['user', function(user) { user.isAuthenticated(); }]
        }
    }
];

    angular.forEach(states, function (state) {
        $stateProvider.state(state.name, state);
    });
```

**This does not work in retrieving the data:**

```
 app.config(['$locationProvider', '$resourceProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($locationProvider, $resourceProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  not working --->  var states = $resource('http://localhost:9669/api/breeze/states').query();

    angular.forEach(states, function(state) {
        $stateProvider.state(state.name, state);
    });
}]);
```

**My question is two-fold:**

1. How does one retrieve remote data inside app.config so as to populate $StateProvider.
2. I know even when that is acheived, I will have a problem with the return value of

   "['user', function(user) { user.isAuthenticated(); }]"

   as it will come back as a string and angular will not recognize it as a function.
   How can I overcome that issue?

[Side note: the api call does work, the issue is not the api controller.]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Solution]**

Documentation is piece-meal on this matter, but after sewing various posts together I found the answer.

First one must understand that data cannot be populated in the $stateProvider as it is part of app.config because app.config only initializes providers, the actual http service has to be performed in app.run.

*Step 1: Declare 2 Globals, ie. $stateProviderRef and $urlRouterProviderRef references before the app.module and pass the actual $stateProvider & $urlRouterProvider  references to them in app.config:*

```
(function() {
   var id = 'app';

   var $stateProviderRef = null;
   var $urlRouterProviderRef = null;
   ......

   // Create the module and define its dependencies.
   app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
           $stateProviderRef = $stateProvider;
           $urlRouterProviderRef = $urlRouterProvider;
       });
   .......
```

*Step 2: Create a Custom Factory Provider:*

```
app.factory('menuItems', function($http) {
    return {
        all: function() {
            return $http({
                url: 'http://localhost:XXXX/api/menuitems',
                method: 'GET'
            });
        }
    };
});
```

*Step 3: Call the custom provider in app.run:*

```
  app.run(['$q', '$rootScope', '$state','$urlRouter', 'menuItems',
     function($q, $rootScope, $state, $urlRouter, menuItems) {
        breeze.core.extendQ($rootScope, $q);
        menuItems.all().success(function (data) {                        
                angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                    var stateName = 'state_' +  value.OrderNum; //<-- custom to me as I have over 300 menu items and did not want to create a stateName field
                    $stateProviderRef.state(stateName, {url:value.url, templateUrl:value.templateUrl, controller:value.controller });
                });
                   // because $stateProvider does not have a default otherwise
                   $urlRouterProviderRef.otherwise('/');
          });            
           .....
         }
      ]);
```